# Asp Core server constantly building webpack

Tags: asp.net, node.js

I just tried running my .Net Core project for the first time through the command prompt using "dotnet run" and I've got this showing up constantly:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
  webpack built d6c3eec3e4bc2b13edc1 in 65ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
  webpack building...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
  webpack built d6c3eec3e4bc2b13edc1 in 93ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
  webpack building...
```

It never stops. Anyone have an idea what this means? From what I can tell it seems like NodeServices is unable to be built, but I can't determine why looking at my code, and it looks up to date.

Any ideas?